How to use NSIS installer (3.10) with more than 2GB
Looks like NSIS has a problem with packing files larger than 2GB.
Is there a way to pack more than 2 GB with NSIS 3.10?
The following output is generated during build job on Windows Server 2019:
[MAKENSIS] Internal compiler error #12345: error mmapping datablock to 33584718.
[MAKENSIS] Note: you may have one or two (large) stale temporary file(s) left in your temporary directory (Generally this only happens on Windows 9x).

NSIS is limited to 2 GiB of packed data. You can try maximum compression, usually SetCompressor /FINAL LZMA in your .nsi file.
Otherwise you can try

NSISBI
Store some of the files in a .cab appended to the .exe with the CabX plug-in.

Windows .exe files are limited to 4 GiB no matter what you do, there is no way around that.

What's about the WimImage plug-in? Is that also an option?

Probably. The CabX plug-in has been written specifically to allow you to append the .cab to the .exe so there is only one file to distribute.

NSISBI is the solution we prefered. Should be just as freeware as NSIS, right?

I assume it uses the same license, yes.
